# How to get list of all Auth0 users

Tags: java, spring-security, auth0

I want to get list of Auth0 users from Java API (auth0 client). Can i do it? API based on Java+Spring Security.
I have tried to do it with RestTemplate:

```
List findAllUsers(){
    String idToken = RestService.getIdToken()
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer $idToken");
    List users = []
    try{
        ResponseEntity entity = restTemplate.exchange(issuer+"api/v2/users", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(headers), List)
        users = entity.getBody()
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return users
}
```

But i'm getting 403 Forbidden status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. However, you shall need to use an Auth0 `Management Token`.

See [this sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-boot-social-dbconnection-link/blob/master/src/main/java/com/auth0/example/Auth0Impl.java#L91) I wrote, where I do a search (in this case filtering to get a specific user account rather than all users).

You can get Management Token and see the search options [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users). You need to give your management token `read:users` and `read:user_idp_tokens` scopes as per docs.

Would recommend you start by using a tool like Postman to get the correct search, then convert to Java. You can use the snippet and associated dependencies listed in the sample link above `OkHttpClient`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, Postman can be used to `generate` the code from the request you define too. Auth0 currently does not provide a Management API for Java library, but will do so soon.

**Update:**

Here is some working code, just replace with your Management Token and Tenant (for the URL).

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by arcseldon on 07/09/2016.
 */
public class GetUsers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final String MANAGEMENT_TOKEN = "YOUR_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://<YOUR_TENANT>.auth0.com/api/v2/users")
                .get()
                .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + MANAGEMENT_TOKEN)
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println("All done: " + response.body().string());
    }
}
```

Comment: @SergeyLinnik - Excellent - feel free to post comment(s) here if you get any other questions along the way to setup.

Comment: so, a have another one small question. When i try to do request like in your simple, using okhttp, i've got this error:
`{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Bad HTTP authentication header format","errorCode":"Bearer"}`. Can you help with this? Sorry for so stupid question

Comment: Not at all. See this line https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-boot-social-dbconnection-link/blob/master/src/main/java/com/auth0/example/Auth0Impl.java#L102

Comment: You need an HTTP header with key `Authorization` and value `Bearer <your_management_token>`  Did you generate a Management Token using link above in the answer?

Comment: i just copy-paste your code block
`String url = "https://default-app.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users"
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .get()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + managementToken)
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .build();
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122804/discussion-between-sergey-linnik-and-arcseldon).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Library Apache HTTP Client:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and this code works fine :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://domain.auth0.com/api/v2/users");
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(builder.build());
                httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                httpGet.setHeader(
                        "Authorization",
                        "Bearer "+ token);

                HttpResponse responseHttp = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

                HttpEntity entity = responseHttp.getEntity();

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));

                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
```

This code you will give you only 50 users, if your users are over than 50  you have to use this URL :

```
https://domain.auth0.com/api/v2/users?per_page=50&page="+ pageNumber + "&include_totals=true"
```

and you can specify the number of users per page and the page number including the total of users.

the result of this code is a JSON, so the easiest way to parse it by using the Gson library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

and here is an example of parsing a Json String using the Gson Library :

```
 public String parse(String jsonLine) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data");
    JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("translations");
    jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    String result = jobject.get("translatedText").toString();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way with rest template.

```
final String MANAGEMENT_TOKEN = "ManagementToken";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + MANAGEMENT_TOKEN);
        HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
        String url = "https:<//YOUR_DOMAIN>.auth0.com/api/v2/users";
    ResponseEntity<Object>response=restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,httpEntity, Object.class);
```

`

[To genarate MANAGEMENT_TOKEN](https://manage.auth0.com/#/apis/59b660895486cf4d15015905/explorer)

Hope this will help you out